# Applescript and Non-English Characters

Tags: macos, applescript, translation

I made a quick translator app in Applescript which takes the whatever you have on the clipboard and puts it into Google Translate. It works with basic A-Z and a few symbols. If the app does not recognize the character, it just writes "a". I need it to support non-Latin charecters, like Japanese and symbols. I tried adding the "as Unicode text" at the end of line 2, but that did not work.

```
get the clipboard
set translateMe to the clipboard as Unicode text
tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://translate.google.com"
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke translateMe
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the URL-Syntax like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/" & (the clipboard)
end tell
```